# How do I use a Ruby script to add method to delayed job

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I have a rubyscript in **/myapp/scripts/myscript.rb**
when i run `ruby script/myscript.rb` it executes fine, but how do I run this method with delayed job from within a ruby script? Hope this makes sense
---myscript.rb---

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = ARGV.first || ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || 'development'
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../config/environment")

def populate

    #do some stuff here

end
handle_asynchronously :populate
```

I get a **undefined method 'handle_asynchronously'** error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think handle_asynchronously works only on methods and not on top-level functions.
Maybe you can declare a module like this:

```
# scripts/myscript.rb
class Tasks
  def populate
    puts "Populating..."
  end
  handle_asynchronously :populate
end
# call it in some function
def my_user_task
  Tasks.new.populate
end
```

Comment: Thanks Ill give this a try tommorrow and let you know! :)

Comment: where do I define this module and how do I execute or call it?

Comment: It should work on any object. If you don't have an class to include the module, you can just define a class instead.